# Простой foreign select

Tags: python, django, orm

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выборку по foreign key?
На postgresql запрос, который мне нужен выглядит так:

```
SELECT * from books, stock where stock.book_id = books.id
```

А вот на Django ORM у меня особо не получается повторить:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from firstapp.models import Seller, Stock, Books

def home(request):
    data = Stock.objects.select_related('book').get(Books.id=Stock.book) # я пытался :)
    p = data.title
    return render(request, "home.html", {"context": p})
```

Собственно описание самих таблиц на djang'е

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_delivery = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    discount = models.ForeignKey(Discount, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    storehouse = models.ForeignKey('Storehouse', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stock'

class Books(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cost = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    isbn = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    publish_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    average_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    author_0 = models.ForeignKey(Author, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='author_id', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed because of name conflict.
    publishing_house = models.ForeignKey('PublishingHouse', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'books'
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас и так связаны модели **Stock** и **Books**, нет нужды их ещё раз связывать в запросе. Возьмём **Stock** с существующей **book**

```
Stock.objects.filter(book__isnull=False).select_related('book')
```

И добавим интересующие поля:

```
 all_data = list(Stock.objects.filter(book__isnull=False).select_related('book').values('date_of_delivery', 'discount', 'book__id', 'book__title', 'book__author'))
```

В результате получим список из словарь с данными, остальные поля можно по аналогии описать.